# Failed to install umbraco 7.5.4 via Nuget/Package Manager in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: umbraco

After opening VS 2010, I created an empty MVC 4 Web app 'UmbracoTest' along with a new solution. View engine is Razor and .Net 4. In Package Manager console, I typed PM>install-package umbracocms and prompt this:

```
PM> install-package umbracocms
Attempting to resolve dependency 'UmbracoCms.Core (= 7.5.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc (≥ 5.2.3 && < 6.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor (≥ 3.2.3 && < 3.3.0)'.
...
...
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
...
...
Removing 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.20710.0' from UmbracoTest.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 2.0.20710.0' from UmbracoTest.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3' to UmbracoTest.
Uninstalling 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.2.3'.     You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramewo
rk,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references     or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, 
contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16 
+ install-package <<<<  umbracocms
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],   InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId :    NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says: `You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'`. Umbraco depends on ASP.NET MVC 5 which doesn't work on .NET 4.0. In fact, VS2010 does not support .NET 4.5. Instead you will need Visual Studio 2012 or higher.

There is a free community edition [download of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) available if you're a student, open source developer or individual developer.